# Making Progress

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #1: Restricted Title: xkcd 1xxx](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/)</sub>

---

Why is this taking so long to load?

[image]

---

[Relevant stillframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbC7J.png) <sup>(can be solved without the .gif, but the animation does contain one hint)</sup>

---

Hints:

> Looking at the GIF, you can see that the current shape is always offset by about 30° after each anti-clockwise rotation. No further information from the GIF is needed, everything else is also in the PNG.

> Black lines will need to be added to the shape

Comment: I think this might be one of those puzzles that looks difficult but once we see the answer, we will kick ourselves for not thinking of it! I have spent a few hours at least on this, no luck yet.

Comment: ^ Same, I've been looking at this for ages but I have no idea how to process it. I had already observed before the hint was released that rot13(rnpu evat-yvxr funcr'f raq fgngr jnf bssfrg ol n ovg sebz vgf vavgvny fgngr), and while I was happy that the hint confirmed that, I am still basically stuck as I did not obtain any new significant information. D:

Comment: Maybe rot13 Gur vzntrf cbvag gb ahzoref ba n pybpx naq jr pna znxr fbzrguvat bs gung?

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking the same, but I still have no leads...

Comment: It is probably off topic but is the [delay in GIF](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/117046/revisions#panel-b0347646-6fd1-4986-91b1-ac5cfac82f89-SideBySideHtml) a thing we are supposed to notice or is it something to not care about.

Comment: @VarunW. I only did that to visualize clearly when the relevant states inside the gif are, i.e. all the stillframes.

Comment: Just to be sure... no knowledge other than trivial is needed?

Comment: @Prim3numbah Correct.

Comment: Have tried one or two things with n frira-frtzrag qvfcynl but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere, back to trying things out

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Looking at the gif, each shape rotates 390° counterclockwise, or 30° more than a full rotation. We can imagine that this extra rotation is actually retained by the next shape, and the one after that. In other words, the second shape is 30° counterclockwise offset from its original position, the third shape is 60° offset, the fourth shape is 90° offset, etc. Thus, to find the original, unrotated shapes, we can rotate each shape clockwise by that amount. Doing so gets the following shapes:
>  [image: Rotation Image]

> Now we can look at the crosses associated with each shape. If a cross has its vertical line shaded black, then the shape must have a vertical line added. Likewise, if its horizontal line is shaded, then we must add a horizontal line. This results in the following:
>  [image: Added Rectangles Image]

> We can now read out the final answer to the puzzle: **WHILE(TRUE)**.

Comment: Very impressive. I wouldn't have gotten that given infinite time. Lol. Still a great puzzle!

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer:**

I can't shake the idea the frames correspond to

> semaphore letters

with the gaps indicating

> the flag positions

Which taking the png at face value yields

> U_LQ  / TERI / ENM

assuming I've looked them up correctly.

That doesn't help much, so possibly the line on the cross indicates

> The orientation you should look at certain frames from

but I haven't yet found a combination that works.

Comment: Semaphore is not used in this puzzle.